# Overflow scroll and show context menu

Tags: css, overflow, icefaces

I've got div with overflow="scroll" on it, which is displaying content (icefaces app). I've got event for right mouse button with displaying context menu of element of this content, but context menu is displaying inside of this div, i must scroll to see this context menu. This context menu is hidden div - after mouse click it's set to visible.

It's physically putted inside of scroll panel (and it unfortunatelly must be inside). Anyone have idea how to resolve this problem (i tried everything from google). Maybe some js trick or something like that? ;)

Problem is that i need it out of this scroll ;)

Thanks a lot.
Matthew

Comment: can you show code and make a fiddle?

Comment: I would like make green square out of scroll panel ( green square simulate opened context menu for element in red square.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LGBAH/3/

Comment: You want the green square be outside of the scrolling area?

Comment: I understand you can't change the html.. can u use jquery?